# ¿como pasar de un panel a otro con un botón?

Tags: jframe

Buenas tengo un formulario con una clase persona una clase formulario con un array lito un Jframe formulario y un Jframe para el toString de formularios.
Entonces mi idea es la siguiente yo tengo un panel donde hay 2 botones agregar usuario y otro ver usuarios.
Soy muy nuevo en Jframe y no tengo demasiada idea. Como hago para que se abra el panel de agregar usuarios al darle clic a ese botón?
Esta es mi Jframe de formulario para que os hagáis una idea

```
public class InterfazToString extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form InterfazToString
     */
    Formulario f;

    public InterfazToString() {
        try {
            f = deserializa();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String mensaje = "No existe el archivo txt";
        }
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        txtToString = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        txtToString.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txtToStringActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addComponent(txtToString, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 363, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(18, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addComponent(txtToString, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 237, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(35, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void txtToStringActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
       f.toString();
    }                                           

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InterfazToString.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InterfazToString.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InterfazToString.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InterfazToString.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new InterfazToString().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtToString;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    public static Formulario deserializa() {
        FileInputStream miFis = null;
        ObjectInputStream miOis = null;
        Formulario f = null;
        try {
            String miFichero = "PilaDePartes.dat";
            miFis = new FileInputStream(miFichero);
            miOis = new ObjectInputStream(miFis);
            boolean seguir = true;
            while (seguir) {
                try {
                    f = (Formulario) miOis.readObject();

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(InterfazFormulario.class
                            .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (EOFException endOfFileException) {
                    seguir = false;

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(InterfazFormulario.class
                            .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            miOis.close();
            miFis.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(InterfazFormulario.class
                    .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                miFis.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(InterfazFormulario.class
                        .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {
                miOis.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(InterfazFormulario.class
                        .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return f;
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Con este codigo habres cualquier formulario    dentro del panel solo manda a llamar el metodo y mandale el formulario que quieres abrir
ejemplo:

```
    private void Cliente_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//boton cliente
    {
        InsertPanel(new Agregarliente());//AgregarCliente es el nombre de un formulario
    }

    private void InsertPanel(Object form)//metodo parametrico que recibe un objeto de tipo formulario
    {
        try//se coloca un try-catch por el hecho de que si hay errores
        {
            abrecliente.Visible = false; //abrecliente es el nombre de otro panel que tiene 3 botone (no le tomes importancia)
            if (this.panel4.Controls.Count > 0)//se lee como: si el panel 4 tiene algun contenido entonces...(el panel4 es donde abro los formularios) 
                this.panel4.Controls.RemoveAt(0);//se remueve lo que tiene adentro(esto mas que nada es para que no se sobreponga un mismo panel que abras dos veces)
            Form AC = form as Form;//se crea una variable de tipo formulario (que se utiliza para asignarle el objeto que esta recibiendo).
            AC.TopLevel = false;//quita el componente de minimizar, maximizar, cerrar del formulario que se esta abriendo.
            AC.Parent = panel4;//esta colocando el formulario en el panel
            AC.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;//se asigna el borde que tendra
            AC.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;//que sea fijo
            AC.Location = new Point(186, 40);//la posicion de donde va a comenzar el formulario.
            AC.Show();//se abre el formulario en el panel
            panel4.Visible = true;//se muestra el panel (con el formulario ya puesto)
            abrecliente.Visible = false;//ignoralo
            abrirpoliza.Visible = false;//ignoralo
            abrirherramientas.Visible = false;//ignoralo (ya que son 3 paneles mas donde guardo botones para mi menu)
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Surgio un error " + ex);
        }  
    }
```

Es lo que te entendi que quieres... y si quieres abrir el panel como tal, te recomiendo que ocultes primero el panel, despues lo llenes y despues de llenarlo lo pongas visible

Comment: me puedes explicar como funciona es que estoy un poco verde

Comment: listo bro, ya te lo comente, espero y sea lo que buscas.

Comment: No me queda claro a ver yo tengo 3clases Jframe si quieres llamarlo asi, una pricipal con 2 botones listar y añadir. La idea es que al dar al boton añadir se abra el panel de la clase InterfazFormulario que es dodne esta el formulario creado. No se como adaptar ese metodo a mi proyecto